# How to Install Microsoft Windows OS if already have Ubuntu 12.04 installed

Tags: ubuntu, windows, system-installation, dual-boot

I have purchased a Dell laptop with Ubuntu Linux 12.04 installed in it, and I want to install Microsoft Windows operating system on Ubuntu and have dual booting. I hope to install the Microsoft Windows OS into a different drive than the one where Ubuntu is already installed. For example – if we have Ubuntu operating system in the the first drive, then I want to install Microsoft Windows Operating System in the second. I don't want to uninstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you considered virtual box? This way you can run Microsoft's windows inside a Ubuntu window, or on a virtual desktop. You can then switch between them quickly and drag & drop from one to the other. It will also be more secure as Microsoft's windows will not be able to infect the other system (Ubuntu).

Comment: C: and D: drive will be an alien concept to most people. It is only used on C/PM, Dos, and Microsoft's Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a second hard drive. All you need is a second **partition**.

The procedure in brief is as follows:

1. BACKUP IMPORTANT DATA
2. Create a new partition
3. Install Windows in this new partition
4. Reinstall Grub (the bootloader)

## BACKUP IMPORTANT DATA

These are major operations and while they should not cause data loss, a power outage, a crash or human error might erase your data so, better safe than sorry.

## Create a new partition

For this you'll need a liveUSB or liveDVD. Create a liveUSB using Unetbootin or Startup Disc creator.
Boot from this liveUSB and use gparted to create a new partition. Depending on your current partitioning you may have to reduce the size of the Ubuntu partition.
Once you do this, reboot and check that Ubuntu is still working properly.

## Install Windows in this new partition

Now you will need a Windows DVD. Install it but make sure you choose to install it in the freshly created partition, not the whole drive.
This will remove the Ubuntu bootloader rendering Ubuntu unbootable.

## Reinstall Grub (the bootloader)

Next boot the live DVD or live USB again. Open Files and click on the Ubuntu drive to mount it.
Then open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and type: `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`. Change the 'X' to the letter of your drive. If you only have one hard drive it should be `/dev/sda`.
Reboot and you should see GRUB with the options to boot Ubuntu or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Backup data on external drive and delete all the partitions,format the disk then start to install the OS whichever you want.